# Git doesn't recognize changes on NTFS

Tags: git, ntfs

I'm using `git` under Linux in VMware, where the host operating system is Windows 7. The git repository is in NTFS partition of Windows. Sometimes I overwrite the content of the git repository but `git` doesn't notice the changes. Neither `git status` nor `git diff` shows anything. But I know, that there are changes. How to force `git` to update or reflush (or I don't know what to do) the NTFS filesystem?

Comment: I don't imagine this is an issue with NTFS. I've used git on a shared drive with no problems. Is anything being ignored by git?

Comment: No, certainly not. This is strange. When I first unzipped the content of a `.zip` to the repository, it showed me the changes. Then I did `git reset --hard` and `git clean -f` and unzipped the same file again. But this time the changed files were not shown.  And also: I noticed problems with rebasing on the same filesystem... `git rebase` on the same version of branch sometimes worked, sometimes didn't

Comment: How are you mounting the drive from the host to the guest?

Comment: I use Folder Sharing in VMware. Invoking `mount | grep hgfs` gives me result `.host:/ on /mnt/hgfs type vmhgfs (rw,relatime)`